# Why Networkx Output for Betweenness Centrality is wrong?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to calculate betweenness for a simple graph with 6 nodes:

```
G=nx.Graph()
e=[(1,2),(1,5),(2,3),(3,6),(5,6),(4,2),(4,3)]
G.add_edges_from(e)
btw=nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
```

As I calculated for each node the output should be:

```
{1: 1.5, 2: 2.5, 5: 1, 3: 2.5, 6: 1.5, 4: 0}
```

But the output is :

```
{1: 0.15000000000000002,
 2: 0.25,
 5: 0.1,
 3: 0.25,
 6: 0.15000000000000002,
 4: 0.0}
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're calculating the non-normalized centrality, whereas by default [`betweenness_centrality`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html) has `normalized` set to `True`.

Instead set it to `False`:

```
G=nx.Graph()
e=[(1,2),(1,5),(2,3),(3,6),(5,6),(4,2),(4,3)]
G.add_edges_from(e)
btw=nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=False)
# {1: 1.5, 2: 2.5, 5: 1.0, 3: 2.5, 6: 1.5, 4: 0.0}
```